# What's a good way to "fuse" the locations pointed to by different pointers?

Tags: perl, pointers, memory, reference, hdl

I have many pointers pointing to different (or same) locations in memory. I want to implement a mechanism that allows us to "fuse" the locations pointed to by a given subset of the pointers.

I am using perl 5.6.1 right now, but I am open to implementations in other languages. I came up with the following dumb implementation in perl:

```
my $ref1 = \1;
my $ref2 = \2;
print "${$ref1} : ${$ref2}\n"; # <-- prints 1 : 2

fuse(\$ref1, \$ref2);          # <-- Make $ref2 point to same location as $ref1
print "${$ref1} : ${$ref2}\n"; # <-- prints 1 : 1 (which is correct)

sub fuse
{
    ${$_[1]} = ${$_[0]}; 
}
```

But this doesn't work as expected when we have to fuse more than once:

```
my $ref1 = \1;
my $ref2 = \2;
my $ref3 = \3;
print "${$ref1} : ${$ref2} : ${$ref3}\n"; # <-- prints 1 : 2 : 3

fuse(\$ref1, \$ref2);                     # <-- Make $ref2 point to same location as $ref1
print "${$ref1} : ${$ref2} : ${$ref3}\n"; # <-- prints 1 : 1 : 3 (which is correct)

fuse(\$ref3, \$ref1);                     # <-- Make $ref1 point to same location as $ref3
print "${$ref1} : ${$ref2} : ${$ref3}\n"; # <-- prints 3 : 1 : 3 ($ref2 is useless now)

sub fuse
{
    ${$_[1]} = ${$_[0]}; 
}
```

In the above example, I want all the three variables `$ref1`, `$ref2`, and `$ref3` to finally point to a location which contains `3`.

Is there a good way to accomplish this "fusing" without manually re-assigning every pointer whose referent we want to change?

**Context:**
I am trying to simulate a circuit (which has wires). When two nodes are connected by a wire, one of the attributes of both the nodes (let's say voltage) becomes the same. When one of these nodes is connected to a third node (with a wire), the voltages at all the three nodes become the same irrespective of what values they had previously and continues to remain same as long as the connection exists.

My attempts at googling how HDLs implement wires failed (I probably didn't know what to google).

Comment: Perl doesn't have _pointers_ you are dealing with _references_ here.

Comment: @simbabque, aren't perl _references_ functionally almost identical to _pointers_ in languages like C?

Comment: I don't understand enough C to answer that. They are similar, but not the same. However, for the actual question, I think you ought to explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I think it would be useful for us to know why you want to do this. I suspect you're asking us for help with an implementation detail when asking us for help with the approach to take would be more fruitful. I'm not sure what you're doing, but I'm pretty sure you're going about it the wrong way :-)

Comment: Contrary to your implications, this doesn't work in C either. [demo](https://pastebin.com/bz6LuJav).

Comment: Is it fair to say [this program](https://pastebin.com/sJJw88d2) correctly demonstrates the behaviour you want to achieve?

Comment: @ikegami The implementation in the question wouldn't work in any language (I don't think any language handles memory weirdly enough for this to work). The issue is with the algorithm, not the implementation. I added an answer that seems to have solved my problem.

Comment: Could you answer the question in my second comment please? If you can confirm that's the spec, I can write a solution.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but where's the `fuse` function defined in the link? The outputs are more or less what I want them to be. I'm not really sure why all the outputs became `4` after the three fuses, but this shouldn't really be an issue.

Comment: Re "*I'm not really sure why all the outputs became 4 after the three fuses*", Well, they're all fused, so they can only have one value, right? What value would you expect if not 4? (Note that I reversed the order of the arguments to the more normal `op(dst, src)` order.)

Comment: Since we can set the value before reading the voltage, I would consider the program you posted [here](https://pastebin.com/sJJw88d2) correct.

Comment: So you want to be able to set the values before or after fusing, and you want to be able to fuse any part of a fused set with any part of another fused set. This will requires backreferences like Perl's CoW mechanism uses.

Comment: Using `op(dst, src)`, shouldn't the value be 1 for [this](https://pastebin.com/sJJw88d2) code?

Comment: I am fine with not being able to set the value before fusing. That is the reason I said [this](https://pastebin.com/sJJw88d2) code is fine.

Comment: Re "*shouldn't the value be 1 for this code?*", o2 and o1 become fused with value 1. o3 and o4 become fused with value 4. o3 (and o4) and o1 (and o2) become fused with value 1. Oops yes.

Comment: Re "*I am fine with not being able to set the value before fusing.*", That's "free". The hard part is fusing with part of something already fused.

Comment: Re "_This will requires backreferences like Perl's CoW mechanism uses_", I have no idea about this. It would be really helpful if you could explain this in an answer. (For solving this particular problem, the answer I wrote using the disjoint-set data structure seems to be working. Any solution using a different approach would also be useful.)

Comment: I will. I was working on it, but I gave to go for now. I'll also check your solution to make sure it actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe

- You want to be able to fuse any part of a fused set with any part of another fused set.
- You want to be able to set the values such that every part of the fused set is updated.

Which means the following program defines the expected behaviour:

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;

use Wire qw( );

my $o1 = Wire->new( voltage => 1 );
my $o2 = Wire->new( voltage => 2 );
my $o3 = Wire->new( voltage => 3 );
my $o4 = Wire->new( voltage => 4 );
say join " ", map $_->get_voltage(), $o1, $o2, $o3, $o4;  # 1 2 3 4

$o2->fuse($o1);
$o3->fuse($o4);
$o1->fuse($o3);
say join " ", map $_->get_voltage(), $o1, $o2, $o3, $o4;  # 4 4 4 4

$o1->set_voltage(5);
say join " ", map $_->get_voltage(), $o1, $o2, $o3, $o4;  # 5 5 5 5

$o3->set_voltage(6);
say join " ", map $_->get_voltage(), $o1, $o2, $o3, $o4;  # 6 6 6 6
```

This class achieves that:

```
package Wire;

use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

sub new {
   my ($class, %args) = @_;
   my $voltage = $args{voltage} // 0;
   my $self = bless({}, $class);
   $self->{shared_voltage} = { value => $voltage, backrefs => [] };
   push @{ $self->{shared_voltage}{backrefs} }, \( $self->{shared_voltage} );
   return $self;
}

sub get_voltage { $_[0]{shared_voltage}{value} }
sub set_voltage { $_[0]{shared_voltage}{value} = $_[1]; }

sub fuse {
   my ($self, $new) = @_;
   my $old_sv = $self->{shared_voltage};  my $old_sv_br = $old_sv->{backrefs};
   my $new_sv = $new->{shared_voltage};   my $new_sv_br = $new_sv->{backrefs};
   for my $backref (@$old_sv_br) {
      $$backref = $new_sv;
      push @$new_sv_br, $backref;
   }
}

sub DESTROY {
   my ($self) = @_;
   @{ $self->{shared_voltage}{backrefs} } =
      grep { $_ != \( $self->{shared_voltage} ) }
         @{ $self->{shared_voltage}{backrefs} };
}

1;
```

The result is achieved by storing a list of of references to the fused nodes alongside the shared value. This is the same approach used by Copy-on-Write strings in Perl. The fused structure looks like this:

```
+-$o1--+             +-Wire----------------+
| Ref -------------->| +-shared_voltage--+ |               +-anon hash------+
+------+   +---------->| Reference      ------------------>| +-value------+ |
           |         | +-----------------+ |   / / /       | | 4          | |
           |         +---------------------+   | | |       | +-backrefs---+ |
           |                                   | | |       | | Reference -------+
           |                                   | | |       | +------------+ |   |
+-$o2--+   |         +-Wire----------------+   | | |       +----------------+   |
| Ref -----(-------->| +-shared_voltage--+ |   | | |                            |
+------+   | +-------->| Reference      -------+ | |   +------------------------+
           | |       | +-----------------+ |     | |   |
           | |       +---------------------+     | |   |   +-anon array-----+
           | |                                   | |   +-->| +-0----------+ |
           | |                                   | |       | | Reference -------------+
+-$o3--+   | |       +-Wire----------------+     | |       | +-1----------+ |         |
| Ref -----(-(------>| +-shared_voltage--+ |     | |       | | Reference -----------+ |
+------+   | | +------>| Reference      ---------+ |       | +-2----------+ |       | |
           | | |     | +-----------------+ |       |       | | Reference ---------+ | |
           | | |     +---------------------+       |       | +-3----------+ |     | | |
           | | |                                   |       | | Reference -------+ | | |
           | | |                                   |       | +------------+ |   | | | |
+-$o4--+   | | |     +-Wire----------------+       |       +----------------+   | | | |
| Ref -----(-(-(---->| +-shared_voltage--+ |       |                            | | | |
+------+   | | | +---->| Reference      -----------+                            | | | |
           | | | |   | +-----------------+ |                                    | | | |
           | | | |   +---------------------+                                    | | | |
           | | | |                                                              | | | |
           | | | |                                                              | | | |
           | | | +--------------------------------------------------------------+ | | |
           | | +------------------------------------------------------------------+ | |
           | +----------------------------------------------------------------------+ |
           +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(The order of the backrefs is not accurately represented.)

I think you'll find this much faster in practice than [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50935368/589924). Like in yours, fusing is O(N). However, getting and setting the voltage is O(1) instead of O(N). And while object destruction is O(N) instead of O(1) in mine, it could be made O(1) by using a hash instead of an array for the backrefs. That said. It's probably practically faster as an array. This is what Perl does for CoW strings.  N is the size of the fusing (4 in our test case).

Answer (score 2):

I almost gave up before stumbling upon this marvelous thing called [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) which seems to have been invented for solving this exact problem. The following is the code I used:

```
use Scalar::Util qw( weaken );

my $ref1 = {}; $ref1->{voltage} = 1; weaken( $ref1->{parent} = $ref1 );
my $ref2 = {}; $ref2->{voltage} = 2; weaken( $ref2->{parent} = $ref2 );
my $ref3 = {}; $ref3->{voltage} = 3; weaken( $ref3->{parent} = $ref3 );
my $ref4 = {}; $ref4->{voltage} = 4; weaken( $ref4->{parent} = $ref4 );

print "@{[map(get_vol($_), ($ref1, $ref2, $ref3, $ref4))]}\n";
# Above line print 1 2 3 4

fuse($ref1, $ref2); # <-- Second argument gets set to first
print "@{[map(get_vol($_), ($ref1, $ref2, $ref3, $ref4))]}\n";
# Above line print 1 1 3 4

fuse($ref4, $ref3);
set_vol($ref3, 5);
print "@{[map(get_vol($_), ($ref1, $ref2, $ref3, $ref4))]}\n";
# Above line print 1 1 5 5

fuse($ref2, $ref3);
set_vol($ref3, 7);
print "@{[map(get_vol($_), ($ref1, $ref2, $ref3, $ref4))]}\n";
# Above line print 7 7 7 7


sub fuse
{
    my ($node1, $node2) = ($_[0], $_[1]);
    $node2 = $node2->{parent} while ($node2->{parent} != $node2);
    $node2->{parent} = $node1;
}

sub get_vol
{
    my $node = shift;
    $node = $node->{parent} while ($node != $node->{parent});
    return $node->{voltage};
}

sub set_vol
{
    my $node = shift;
    $node = $node->{parent} while ($node != $node->{parent});
    $node->{voltage} = shift;
}
```

After this, setting any of the `$ref`s using `set_vol` will reflect in the `get_vol` output of all the other `$ref`s.

Apparently, we can add other optimizations in reading and setting the voltage so that we don't have to traverse the entire tree when reading or writing for some nodes.

---

**Update**: The following uses the simple principle as above, but avoids memory leaks without using `weaken`, and it optimizes the voltage lookups (so that only the first lookup after a fuse is "slow").

```
package Wire;

use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

sub new {
   my ($class, %args) = @_;
   my $voltage = $args{voltage} // 0;
   my $self = bless({}, $class);
   $self->{voltage_indirect_chain} = { next => undef, value => $voltage };
   return $self;
}

sub _tail {
   my ($self) = @_;
   $self->{voltage_indirect_chain} = $self->{voltage_indirect_chain}{next}
      while $self->{voltage_indirect_chain}{next};

   return $self->{voltage_indirect_chain};
}

sub get_voltage { $_[0]->_tail()->{value} }
sub set_voltage { $_[0]->_tail()->{value} = $_[1]; }

sub fuse {
   my ($self, $new) = @_;
   my $tail = $self->_tail();
   delete $tail->{value};
   $tail->{next} = $new->_tail();
}

1;
```

Comment: There is no funky pointer logic involved in this implementation. Of course, it would be much more usable if put inside an object with a constructor and all.

Comment: [Confirmed to work](https://pastebin.com/J1DdxDkY). Getting/setting the voltage is O(N) whereas a solution exists where it's O(1). This could make a huge difference it you often get/set the voltage.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for fixing the memory leak. But unfortunately, I'm using perl 5.6.1 and Scalar::Util isn't installed on my system. I guess we have to do some `undef`s manually to prevent leaks on older versions such as this.

Comment: It would make far more sense to just install the module. There's no reason it wouldn't install on Solaris

Answer (score 1):

This basic implementation relies on a class attribute, with all disjoint groups of "fused" nodes, keyed by their values. They are updated and merged as needed with each fusing.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use lib $RealBin;         # to load from ./
#use Data::Dump qw(dd);

use Nodes;

my $n1 = Nodes->new(volt => 10);
my $n2 = Nodes->new(volt => 20);
my $n3 = Nodes->new(volt => 30);
my $n4 = Nodes->new(volt => 40);

say "\nFuse n1 with (set to) n3:";
$n1->fuse_with($n3);  # n1 is now at same voltage as n3
say "\tvoltage for node ", $_->label, " is: ", $_->volt
    for ($n1, $n2, $n3, $n4);

say "\nFuse n4 with (set to) n2:";
$n4->fuse_with($n2);  # n4 is now same as n2
say "\tvoltage for node ", $_->label, " is: ", $_->volt
    for ($n1, $n2, $n3, $n4);

say "\nFuse n1 with (set to) n4:";
$n1->fuse_with($n4);  # n1 is now same as n4, and so are n2 and n3
say "\tvoltage for node ", $_->label, " is: ", $_->volt
    for ($n1, $n2, $n3, $n4);

# dd \%Nodes::Fused;
```

**Nodes.pm**

```
package Nodes;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
#use Data::Dump qw(dd);

our $Label = 0;
our %Fused;   # disjoint groups ( value => { label => node, ... }, ... )

sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;
    my $self = { _volt => $args{volt}, _label => ++$Label };  
    say "New node: volt = ", $self->{_volt}, ", label = ", $self->{_label};
    $Fused{$self->{_volt}} = { $self->{_label} => $self };
    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub volt {
    my ($self, $val) = @_; 
    $self->{_volt} = $val if $val;
    return $self->{_volt};
}

sub label { return $_[0]->{_label} }

sub fuse_with {
    my ($self, $node) = @_; 
    # Retrieve groups that have $self or $node
    my %groups = map { 
        ( exists $Fused{$_}->{$self->{_label}} or
          exists $Fused{$_}->{$node->label} )
            ? ($_ => $Fused{$_}) : ()  
    } keys %Fused;
    # Add these nodes if they are in no groups, or
    # Remove %groups from %Fused, fuse them into new one, update voltage
    if (not keys %groups) {
        $Fused{$node->volt}->{$_->label} = $_  for ($self, $node);
        $self->{_volt} = $node->volt;
    }   
    else {
        delete $Fused{$_} for keys %groups;
        $Fused{$node->volt} = { map { %{$groups{$_}} } keys %groups };
        $Fused{$node->volt}->{$node->label}    //= $node;  #/
        $Fused{$node->volt}->{$self->{_label}} //= $self;  #/
        $Fused{$node->volt}->{$_}->{_volt} = $node->volt  
            for keys %{$Fused{$node->volt}};
    }
    # dd \%Fused;
}   

sub cleanup {
    my ($self, $voltage) = @_;
    if ($voltage) {  # new voltage (and label) for the fused group
        $Fused{$voltage} = $Fused{$self->{_volt}};
        delete $Fused{$self->{_volt}};
        $Fused{$voltage}->{$_}->{_volt} = $voltage
            for keys %{$Fused{$voltage}};
    }
    $self->DESTROY;
}

# Must be called manually, via cleanup(), when object leaves scope
sub DESTROY {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return if ${^GLOBAL_PHASE} eq 'DESTRUCT';
    delete $Fused{$_}->{$self->{_label}}  for keys %Fused;
}       

return 1;
```

This prints

```
New node: volt = 10, label = 1
New node: volt = 20, label = 2
New node: volt = 30, label = 3
New node: volt = 40, label = 4

Fuse n1 with (set to) n3:
        voltage for node 1 is: 30
        voltage for node 2 is: 20
        voltage for node 3 is: 30
        voltage for node 4 is: 40

Fuse n4 with (set to) n2:
        voltage for node 1 is: 30
        voltage for node 2 is: 20
        voltage for node 3 is: 30
        voltage for node 4 is: 20

Fuse n1 with (set to) n4:
        voltage for node 1 is: 20
        voltage for node 2 is: 20
        voltage for node 3 is: 20
        voltage for node 4 is: 20
```

Uncomment (and add) prints of `%Nodes::Fused` to see how "fused" groups are kept track of.

This approach comes with the following demand: If an object is to be destroyed (going out of scope) the destructor need be called explicitly. There is `cleanup()` method provided for that

```
{ # lexical will go out of scope while the object is in fused groups
    my $n5 = Node->new(volt => 500);
    $n2->fuse_with($n5);
    $n5->cleanup(25);    # with new voltage for the group (optional)
}
```

The reason is precisely the convenient class attribute, which keeps references to objects so the destructor isn't called automatically.

The alternative is to have the "fused" lists in each object. This gets expensive if there are many nodes and fusing is often since each object must rework the whole list, *O(N<sup>2</sup>)*. This is a possible scenario in modeling a circuit and for that reason I kept the class attribute.

A few more comments

- This does what it needs to but it has missing bits and pieces
- It relies on a class attribute, what isn't the cleanest design if it is involved. It entangles objects, creating a global entity, what is in principle against independence of objects
- Some basic methods are missing, in particular to "unfuse" a node and to independently set a new value (and update all fused nodes if needed)
- Needs checks. Needs some low level optimizations

Comment: @ikegami Updated, and kept the class data.  Thank you for comments.